# Add text to email template if order contains virtual product

Tags: virtual-products

I am thinking of selling tickets using the virtual product function. Therefore I would like to add text to the email template only if an virtual product is present. Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible but please tell me what template you want it in, I will help you then.

Comment: Thank you Toon. I would like to add it to the order confirmation for both logged in users and guests.
I would simply like to add a little text before the order ID like "Please show this order confirmation at the shop to receive your tickets".

Comment: Well looks like @R.S beat me to it, this is a correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the easer way would be to include a pthml file to your email

Add code below to location where text to be display in your email template

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='<module_name>/orderemail.phtml' order=$order}}
```

in your template file /orderemail.phtml

```
$_order = this->getOrder()
$hasVirtual = false;

 $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
 foreach($items as $i){
    if( $i->->getIsVirtual()){
         $hasVirtual = true;
    }
 }

 if($hasVirtual){
    echo 'text here
 }
```