# Transactional emails of virtual products containing specific instructions?

Tags: email-templates, transactional

I was wondering if Transactional Emails can be customised by product so if I send a virtual product rather than an actual item, the customer would  receive an order confirmation with specific instructions?

Comment: possible duplicate http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43222/add-text-to-email-template-if-order-contains-virtual-product

Comment: You can use downloadable product instead of virtual.